# How to compare value with other values in range easily

Tags: excel, vba

could someone help, how to rewrite folowing condition somehow smarter (and definitely shorter)?

It should pretty much say: If value in one specific cell is not empty and at the same time is different from any value in cells from X32 to X47 → do something

Thanks a lot!

```
For i = 4 To 69
    If Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> "" _
        And Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> Range("X32") And Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> Range("X33") And Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> Range("X34") And Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> Range("X35") _
        And Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> Range("X36") And Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> Range("X37") And Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> Range("X38") And Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> Range("X39") _
        And Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> Range("X40") And Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> Range("X41") And Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> Range("X42") And Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> Range("X43") _
        And Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> Range("X44") And Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> Range("X45") And Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> Range("X46") And Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> Range("X47") Then

            "DO SOMETHING"
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("yourSheetName")
    For i = 4 To 69
        If Not IsEmpty(.Range(SO_COLUMN & i)) And IsError(Application.Match(.Range(SO_COLUMN & i), .Range("X32:X47"), 0)) Then
            'do something
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs That is kind. Thank you.

Comment: The "IsEmpty" part does not work, so i replaced it with original Range(SO_COLUMN & i) <> "" and the rest works perfectly. Thank you very much :)

Comment: you are welcome. Do you perhaps have formulas in the cells? You can use <> vbNullString for faster comparisons than "".

Comment: You are perfectly right, I do have formulas in there. 
I adjust as you recomend and it works smoothly :) Thank you again.